# how do I resize the area of the prototype cell in storyboard

Tags: uitableview, storyboard

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  The size of the tableviewcell is wrong.
How do I reduce the size of the area where "prototype cells" is standing?  I can't find it.

[image: Protoype cells]

What do I have to change in the storyboard to reduce it.
I am using Tableview in a normal Viewcontroller

In a Tableviewcontroller it looks normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to change this behaviour:

From the Interface Builder:

- Select the `view controller`;
- Find the `Adjust scroll view insets` option; and
- Uncheck it.